# using sqlite database with Windows store app

Tags: windows, sqlite, winrt-xaml

I guess I am not the first one who encount this issue, but can't find much information after a bit of research. Here is my question:

- A windows store app access a sqlite database, the database contains a
  few tables, and it is read only. The size of database is 20 MB.
- at   the starting of the App, it will copy the database to
  application    folder (if it is not already there). It works fine,
  when i test it    manually (although it is not lighting fast). but it
  always failed    badly when testing again the certification test
  toolkits, failed at    the preformance test with "app crash" or "app
  can start" error.

so my question is

- 1) is this the correct way of using sqlite database in    windows
  store app? (i mean using a 20MB database locally) or should i    port
  the data to cloud?
- 2) is the failure of the certification    toolkit really matter? (
  will it also means failure of publishing    process?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going on perfect way. If your app doesn't need Internet connectivity at all then don't go for cloud database. You should use extended splash screen to copy the database, you should not do that thing in `App.xaml.cs`. If you use cloud database then it will require more time for request-response. I think SQLite transaction is faster than that.

The certification may fail, if you are not using latest version of [WACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/jj572486.aspx). If your app fails WACK test, it won't be published.

Comment: Thanks, extend splash screen works! i got a "passed with warning". But another question is whether it is possible to get the database copied during the installation of the App?

Comment: No, it's not possible.